# making a function including a derivative of other equations as variables

Tags: function-construction, calculus-and-analysis

I'm trying to make a function where I'm making a derivative of a polynomial but it does not work as I expect. Consider this example

```
poly1=a*x^2 + t
poly2=D[poly1,x]
fun1[x_,t_]:=D[a*x^2 + t,x]
fun2[x_,t_]:=D[poly1,x]
fun3[x_,t_]:=poly2
```

now if I put

```
fun1[y,z]
```

or

```
fun3[y,z]
```

the result is what I want/expect:

$2ay$

but if I put

```
fun2[y,z]
```

the result is

$0$

Why is that?

I have a very long polynomial which I want to define as a function of derivatives of some polynomials of x and t. how I can solve the issue?

P.S. I have absolutely no idea what should I put as tag here!

Comment: When you pass `y` to `fun2` in the `x` slot, it tries to differentiate `poly1` with respect to `y`, which of course is zero. It works if you make `poly1` a function: `poly1[x_, t_] := a*x^2 + t ` (and call it appropriately).

Comment: @aardvark2012 I'm gonna try it, but strange behaviour! why should Mathematica do that?!

Comment: You should read [tutorial/ImmediateAndDelayedDefinitions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ImmediateAndDelayedDefinitions.html), but this behavior is entirely logical and consistent.